# How to get the user's id with asp.net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-identity

I'm working on a project that uses Identity to store the user information.

So I have a form that allows me to submit data and the information is saved onto the database. But I have an option to allow user anonymousity. I was wondering how to get the user's Id so that I can apply it in my if-else statement at the start of the following code.

```
 protected void AddPost(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            var User = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.;
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(Int32.Parse(inputAnonymous.SelectedValue)))
            {
                User = "";
            }

            Post newPost = new Post()
            {
                postTitle = inputTitle.Text,
                postBody = inputBody.Text,
                postDescription = inputDescription.Text,
                postCategory = inputCategory.SelectedValue,
                postAnonymous = Convert.ToBoolean(Int32.Parse(inputAnonymous.SelectedValue)),
                Id = User
            };

            using (var _dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                _dbContext.Posts.Add(newPost);
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

I know that if I use

```
 var User = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Then it will get the users username (email in this context and not the users Id).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are not using Asp.Net core.

there is extension method GetUserId which should help you.

As it is extension method you need to add a using statement.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

strCurrentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId()
```

This namespace can be found in `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using Asp.Net webforms (not MVC). I've enable the "using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" part, but I'm unsure how I'd apply the second part to my if-else statements,